# EasyUI update tab title doesn't work.

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using EasyUI 1.35, trying to update a tab title, but it doesn't work, tab tile doesn't get updated. I am sure that variable tab is not null.

thanks

```
 var tab = $('#tabContainer').tabs('getTab', title);                   
 tab.panel('setTitle', title + " " + '12345');
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the easyui docs, to update the tab, there is the update method available.

So to update the title you would have to use the code this way:

```
var tab = $('#tabContainer').tabs('getTab', title);  // get selected panel
$('#tabContainer').tabs('update', {
    tab: tab,
    options: {
        title: title + " " + '12345'
    }
});
```